# Ubuntu not upgrading 22.04.0

Tags: upgrade

***N: Ignoring file 'anydesk' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension***

when run apt upgrade it show above error why?

Comment: That is not an error, just a notice (--> `N`). You can simply ignore the message or delete that file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk`, because it doesn't do anything anyways. If you say, the upgrade does not work, then you have another error not mentioned in your question

Comment: Here's a solution to the same problem, different filename.. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27940/command-line-linux-distro-for-i386-and-128mb-ram?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Apt checks for filename extensions within the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk.list` will be treated as a valid source, as it has a `.list` filename extension.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk` will be ignored, as it has no extension. That's why you are getting a **N**otice (`N:`) about it. (Not an **E**rror [`E:`] nor a **W**arning [`W:`]).